# Typescript merge deep function without type 'any'

Tags: typescript

How to convert [this answer][1] to typescript without using the type 'any'?

Currently (not working) try:

```
export function isObject(item: object): boolean {
  return !!item && typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item);
}

export function mergeDeep(target: object, ...sources: object[]): object {
  if (!sources?.length) return target;
  const source = sources.shift();

  if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
    for (const key in source) {
      const sk = source[key];
      if (isObject(sk)) {
        if (!target[key]) Object.assign(target, { [key]: {} });
        mergeDeep(target[key], sk);
      } else {
        Object.assign(target, { [key]: source[key] });
      }
    }
  }

  return mergeDeep(target, ...sources);
}


const obj1 = {
  one: {
    two: {
      keep: "yes!",
      change: "should not see me",
    },

    three: {
      four: {
        keep: "yes!",
        change: "should not see me",
      },
    },
  },
};

const obj2 = {
  one: {
    two: {
      change: "NICE 1!!",
    },

    three: {
      four: {
        change: "NICE 2!!",
      },
    },
  },
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(mergeDeep(obj1, obj2), null, 2));
```

Comment: I don't know why you have an issue with `any` being used in places, but maybe [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NaRD9m) meets your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's because the linter complains if `any` is used  and I was trying not to add a linter disable. Your code compiled the function correctly, but when trying to use, it [didn't compile](https://tsplay.dev/wQJ0vN) I saw you continued my approach, if you were going to do it how would you?

Comment: I don't know, you would first need to put the information necessary to understand the question directly in the post as plaintext (not just a link).  It is almost certain that if you need callers to see very strong types (e.g., the output type has keys and values that depend on the keys and values of the input types) then the function implementation will need very loose types (e.g., `any` or the equivalent).  So hopefully you'll [edit] this question to provide a self-contained [mre] with detailed use cases and test input/outputs and we can continue from there.

Comment: What *type* do you want the return value of `mergeDeep(obj1, obj2)` to be?

Comment: If you really don't care about types then you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK33KW), which just returns `unknown` (you can't actually limit to `object` because you might be passing strings or other things in there, especially in the recursive call).  If you do care about types then I need more info in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really care about using very strong types and you just want to get things to compile without [the unsafe `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), you can use the safer [`unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).  And for `isObject()` you can mark it as a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), so that the result will narrow the input to an object type which allows any property key to be accessed:

```
function isObject(item: unknown): item is Record<string, unknown> {
    return !!item && typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item);
}

function mergeDeep(target: unknown, ...sources: unknown[]): unknown {
    if (!sources?.length) return target;
    const source = sources.shift();
    if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
        for (const key in source) {
            const sk = source[key];
            if (isObject(sk)) {
                let tk = target[key];
                if (!tk) tk = target[key] = {};
                mergeDeep(tk, sk);
            } else {
                Object.assign(target, { [key]: source[key] });
            }
        }
    }
    return mergeDeep(target, ...sources);
}
```

That's pretty much the same thing but I changed `target[key]` to a saved `tk` variable because the compiler can't easily tell what happens to an indexed access like that if the key is an arbitrary `string`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) for the relevant open issue about that.

Note that when you're done, the output is just of type `unknown`. You might want the output type to be something more closely tied to the input, so that, for example, `mergeDeep({a: 123}).a` is known to exist and be of type `number`.  But that's out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAjgZwPICMBWBTWACjhjwFsAuZSAawgQHcIBKKk81NZAJQIQCcAJgB40MfnAgBzADTUIdRhAB8yAN7BkW5Pzwww-FAEIj7MsgBkF5DACeABzwIQqUuYC8n5ACIEuAjDeltZGAIL8-ACGtgB06OFRtsRuzADcwAC+wKCQsIgoZHj8UngAInh49oQwkcV6VLT0THIxrWgIBlB4aA0KTRAA2gC6rPKKTOqa2nAuhEbtnd0A-DEANnjSMAAWzDp6Big1dTDp2shQSGLIC-xdyO7XHbfdMWhbMzCEaVNaM8jEmH8RCOJRguysnGw+CINy6zF2GjOZxAAn+FwgVxoeFsqBQsLwCJ+SLO6KuaBo90eiwGWNsQ1OxKRfwBUIChHJ8MmjO5yHWMBsFIeIL0NOx9KJPOmsyMMBou1llOFMFFdMpagyDMlZ0KdXKlWqNDkHM1PIyyDwqzQeC5WrOrNgMUiaDQcCkEGqtVBcjUyBVQyo+L9yAy31tWW54e0ka0un0hmQOpKeqqSpabSeXTQ3yy2VJ-L8OAAjGqiUg8FREYyYAwEBWJYysZUqN5bN0jN4ZPXiVAtpFpOWfG8OqtBMh6PyrdbCh2u8HO7PtroB5XJSiDHXbWdG-Zm620O3O5vtD2+yVm0OwCOxwgJxUE3gZ2HD4yMs+tK-MulgHnkAWAEwlmcZYblWNYgZKJ79s2AByACSADCACiyCFiYj4vvO3KLhU4E8mu-C4bakFnj4cFIcgf5oW+prUWcH50Z2Gq5pcCDrGsCBSIQABSADKGDQa84iSFIMxJImZQVFUBaFnI-7MHIECXqsch-vCqRAA)